# Finding the number of paths in a maze with obstacles

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been working on [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-ii/) leetcode problem, which is essentially finding the number of valid paths in a maze given some `obstacleGrid` matrix. If `obstacleGrid[i][j] == 1`, then we have an obstacle at (i,j) and we have zero otherwise, which a valid spot. We can only move down and right with the goal of starting from the upper left to the bottom right.

I have written the code below:

```
def uniquePathsWithObstacles(self, obstacleGrid):
    # obstruction at the start
    if (obstacleGrid[0][0] == 1): return 0
    # obstruction at the end
    if (obstacleGrid[-1][-1] == 1): return 0
    m, n = len(obstacleGrid), len(obstacleGrid[0])
    memo = [[0] * n] * m
    # starting move
    memo[0][0] = 1
    # now check the first row
    for j in range(1, n):
        memo[0][j] = 1 if (obstacleGrid[0][j] == 0 and memo[0][j-1] != 0) else 0
    # now check the first column
    for i in range(1, m):
        memo[i][0] = 1 if (obstacleGrid[i][0] == 0 and memo[i-1][0] != 0) else 0
    # now check everything else
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if (obstacleGrid[i][j] == 1): memo[i][j] = 0
            else: memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j] + memo[i][j-1]
    return memo[-1][-1]
```

I took the obvious DP approach and I know the idea works but something is wrong with the code; for some reason I don't think my `memo` matrix is being updated properly? I feel like the problem is staring at me in the face but for some reason I can't see it. Any help appreciated!

Edit: For `obstacleGrid = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]` and if I had a `print(memo)` right before the return statement, I get `[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]`. This happens to give me the right answer, but the `memo` matrix is wrong!

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Can you give a simple example of `obstacleGrid` with your result and the expected result?

Comment: Remove `self` from the function definition, unless this is a class method. The code as is gives an error: `TypeError: uniquePathsWithObstacles() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obstacleGrid'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem lies in the line `memo = [[0] * n] * m`.
This does not really create `m`copies of the same list, but instead, it only creates the `[0] * n` list once and then creates `memo` as a list of `m` references to this list. Any change to any of these lists therefore modifies all other lists!

You can try this yourself:

```py
memo = [[0] * 3] * 4
memo[0][1] = 1
print(memo)
```

This gives `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]`.

Instead, you have to initialize each list on their own, e.g.,

```py
memo = []
for i in range(m):
  memo.append([0] * n)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion works. Also `memo = [[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(m)]` worked as well! In terms of good Python coding, is there a preferable way?

Comment: You're right, good idea! Your one-liner is more pythonic, I think. But you could even do `[[0]*n for i in range(m)]`.

Comment: @AyumuKasugano: What you wrote is good and is consistent. The way I see the most is `memo = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)]`, which may be faster if somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do this with recursion as an comparison rather than an answer.

```
import numpy as np

def number_of_paths(obstacles):
    """
    Calculate the number of paths available in a maze with obstacles, with only right and down moves, from top left
    to bottom right.

    Args:
        obstacles (ndarray): binary matrix with 1 representing obstacle

    Returns:
         int: the number of paths
    """
    if obstacles[0,0] == 1:
        raise ValueError  # cannot start on an obstacle
    count = 0
    if obstacles.shape == (2,1):
        return 1
    if obstacles.shape == (1,2):
        return 1
    if obstacles.shape[1] > 1 and obstacles[0,1] == 0:
        count += number_of_paths(obstacles[:,1:])
    if obstacles.shape[0] > 1 and obstacles[1,0] == 0:
        count += number_of_paths(obstacles[1:,:])
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct and 1 line must be updated per the below:

```
    def uniquePathsWithObstacles(self, obstacleGrid):
    # obstruction at the start
    if (obstacleGrid[0][0] == 1): return 0
    # obstruction at the end
    if (obstacleGrid[-1][-1] == 1): return 0
    m, n = len(obstacleGrid), len(obstacleGrid[0])
    memo = [[0] * n for i in range(m)]
    # starting move
    memo[0][0] = 1
    # now check the first row
    for j in range(1, n):
        #memo[0][j] = 1 if (obstacleGrid[0][j] == 0 and memo[0][j-1] != 0) else 0
        memo[0][j] = 1 if (obstacleGrid[0][j] == 0 and memo[0][j-1] != 0) else 0
    # now check the first column
    for i in range(1, m):
        memo[i][0] = 1 if (obstacleGrid[i][0] == 0 and memo[i-1][0] != 0) else 0
    # now check everything else
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if (obstacleGrid[i][j] == 1): memo[i][j] = 0
            else: memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j] + memo[i][j-1]
    return memo[-1][-1]
```